# ssh publickey doesn't work

Tags: ssh, centos5, centos6, file-permissions, public-key

UPDATE: I've solved this strange problem by simply restart `sshd`. However, I'm still wondering why, because I didn't change any configs since the server started.

I have 2 servers, one installed CentOS 5 and the other is CentOS 6. `ssh` publickey works fine on the CentOS 5 one, but it doesn't work on the CentOS 6. I confirmed the permissions of `.ssh` directory, it's fine.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -Z .ssh/
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .
dr-xr-x---. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 ..
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 authorized_keys
-rw-------. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 known_hosts
```

UPDATE: I've tried several permissions, including 600, 644 for `authorized_keys`, and 700, 755 for `.ssh/`, all of them don't work.

`ssh -vvv` gives these message

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/zuohaocheng/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/zuohaocheng/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/zuohaocheng/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Everything in `sshd_config` is as default. Also, I copied publickey through `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: That `authorized_keys` file is dated 2012-03-31.  When did you copy your public key up to the server?  Also, what command are you using on the client to ssh to the server?

Comment: is the format of the authorized_keys right ?

Comment: @Ladadadada `ssh -vvv username@host`. The public key is generated on 2012, so the date should be fine.

Comment: Please show either the error log from the SSH server, or the output of `sshd -d`. Keep in mind that the daemon will only process a single connection when started in debug mode.

Comment: @AndrewB I can only access the server through ssh, so I'm afraid that if I use `sshd -d`, some small mistakes may cause a much more serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong permission for `authorized_keys`. You should unset read permission for group and other.

Comment: Thank you, but after I corrected it to 600, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should set 600 to `authorized_keys` on the ssh-server. You better use `ssh-copy-id ssh-server` for it

Comment: I used `ssh-copy-id` exactly, so I feel strange.

Comment: So you can change `LogLevel` to `DEBUG` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on ssh-server and examine `/var/log/messages`

Comment: ssh will work with 644 on authorized_keys but no more open than that.

Answer (score 1):

The Directory/ file permissions should look as the following:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh 
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

`ls -l ~/.ssh` should show you the chmod permissions. Check if `PermitRootLogin Yes` is enabled since you are copying the pub key generated in root's .ssh directory. This could generate the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried several privileges including this, they all don't work.

Comment: Your authorized_keys should be 644 (rw-r-r) not 600 (rw- - )

Comment: I've tried, but both of 644 and 600 don't work.

Comment: Can you update the post and show what `ls -l ~/.ssh` shows?

Comment: `authorized_keys` is 644 now, I've updated it.

Comment: What permissions does ssh dir have?

Comment: 755. I've tried 700 as well, both don't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7094/discussion-between-val0x00ff-and-haocheng)

Answer (score 1):

What are the permissions on `~/` (your home directory)?  You cannot allow permissions at any level that would allow others to overwrite your `~/.ssh` directory.  If your home directory is anything more permissive than 755, you will be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running selinux, that could be the issue.  The type of the .ssh dir and files underneath should be ssh_home_t.  You can verify with ls -Z, and restore with restorecon -Rv .ssh.

/var/log/secure might have more detailed error messages also.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I've fixed them, but it still doesn't work. Also, that log doesn't give any information.

Answer (score 0):

Permission on authorized_keys must be 600 to make public key authentication work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue and it turns out it's related to the fact that I moved my home directory to another disk (for space reasons) and the default security settings don't like this new place, so thus cannot or will not find my .ssh directory.  Trying to figure out out to update the ssh_home_t settings.